# Customizing ERFC function MATLAB

Tags: matlab

erfc Matlab function is the Complementary Error Function and it's defined by :

```
erfc(x) = 2/sqrt(pi) * integral from x to inf of exp(-t^2) dt
```

I want to change this function to:

```
erfc_change(a+b*R) = 1/2*sqrt(pi) * integral from (a+b*vec_x) to inf of exp(-t^2/2) dt %note here exp(-t^2/2) and vec_x is a vector of values that represent the values of x in the erfc function
```

for using it in least square error curve fitting (constants 'a' and 'b' should be approximated).

So i made a variables change and i had this result :

```
erfc_change(a+b*vec_x) = (sqrt(2*pi)/2)*erfc(a+b*vec_x/sqrt(2))
```

I'm not sure of the reliability of my change of variables.

After this, i perform my Least Square Fitting like this ==> This i runnable code:

```
vec_x=  
[0;0.4636;0.6616;0.8225;0.1095;0.1706;0.2302;0.1603;
 0.2392;0.3245;0.3741;0.5376;0.6675;0.1308;0.1881;
 0.2296;0.03740;0.002600;0.04530;0.02660;0.02990;0.0297];

vec_y=[3.3010;5.5840;7.2970;8.8660;4.1200;5.4140;7.1710;
4.5820;6.5400;6.8220;5.6220;8.0110;8.6600;
3.4010;3.7460;4.7180;2.9260;3.4290;4.2780;2.2480;3.8900;4.359];

options = optimoptions('lsqcurvefit','Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt');
f = @(x,vec_x)(1/sqrt(2))*erfc(x(1)+(x(2)*vec_x/sqrt(2)));  
lsqcurvefit(f,-2,vec_x,vec_y); % the approximation will starts from -2
```

Here i got an error (after executing the above code):

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in @(x,fmpd_dinosaur)(1/sqrt(2))*erfc(x(1)+  
(x(2)*fmpd_dinosaur/sqrt(2)))

Error in lsqcurvefit (line 199)
initVals.F =   feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});

Caused by:
Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation.                    
LSQCURVEFIT cannot continue.
```

I don't understand where this error comes from. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please share some reproducible and legible code. You can use newline followed by four consecutive spaces to format as code. It will look much cleaner that way.

Comment: Please provide runnable code, including how you call `lsqcurvefit`, so that the error can be replicated. Also, your changed function does not seem tomatch the code beneath it.

Comment: ok, i added a runnable code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the `erfc` function.

You got an `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` error while `lsqcurvefit` was evaluating the function that you provided.

This is because your function `f` expects a 2-element parameter vector `x`, but you provided `lsqcurvefit` with an initial guess that contains only one element. Hence it runs into problems when it tries to access the second element `x(2)`.

So in your case the solution is simply to provide an initial guess of the appropriate dimension:

```
>> lsqcurvefit(f,[-2,-2],vec_x,vec_y)

Local minimum found.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient is less than
the default value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>


ans =

  -11.9673   -2.8082
```